# How could I give class active to menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following HTML code segment:

```
<div class="w-nav-item-h" id="mydiv">
<a class="w-nav-anchor level_1" href="/english/about-us/word-from-the-chairman">
<span class="w-nav-title">Word from the Chairman</span>
</a>
</div>
```

I want to give class "active" to the div identified by "mydiv" according to the the page url with this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                $("#mydiv").removeClass('active');

                var lnk = window.location.href;
                lnk = lnk.toLowerCase();
                $("#mydiv a").each(function (index) {
                    if (lnk.indexOf($(this).html().trim().toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-")) != -1) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            });
      </script>
```

Unfortunately it is not working. Please help me to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**replace**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [**regular expression**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to `.replace` will always replace the first occurrence except if you use regular expression.

Also use `.text()` instead of `.html()` to find the text of anchor. i.e. *Word from the Chairman*

*Code*

```
$(function () {
    $("#mydiv").removeClass('active');
    var lnk = window.location.href;
    lnk = lnk.toLowerCase();
    $("#mydiv a").filter(function (index) {
        var thisText = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
        return lnk.indexOf(thisText) > -1;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hZw6F/1/), *In example I have used hard-coded text for url*

Comment: it is working very well. but the first link in the menu not be active .other links working well.. why ??

Comment: @user3584641, Did not get you `the first link in the menu not be active`